# How to put MySQL database online with Wamp?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

My **WAMP server**, **Apache** is online, everything is working. My ports `80` and `3306` are open, I can access my server from outside. I can also access PhpMyAdmin from *"http://MyIPAddress/PhpMyAdmin"*. however, I can't find a way to access my database outside.

For the host parameters I tried:

**`MyPublicIP:3306`** (*Error: Too long to respond* / It **works with localhost**)
I can make php requests with host `127.0.0.1:3306`, it works even online in Php Page, but I can't connect directly my DB online...

I need to connect my database to an application on a remote computer. Except with a VPN, I didn't find any solutions and I searched in all WAMP parameters to put MySQL online.

Comment: that depends on how you have set mysql, whether you have allowed external access in mysql. And if you have allowed access from outside, whether the user can also access from outside, because in mysql you can allow individual users to access different hosts. that is a very complicated story.

Comment: sounds most likely you need to specify bind address in your server configuration; what mysql version is this?

Comment: Ahah thank you Max: The Users can access to any host, but I don't find settings to change localhost to public IP... Maybe in WAMP parameters?
@ysth : My version is: 5.7.21, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if your MySQL is bind to localhost or any host (0.0.0.0 or *)

If its already bind to any host, the next would be to see if your firewall/router is allowing the port, you might need to do a port forwarding on your router.

Comment: Hello Kyle, thank you for your help. In PhpMyAdmin, my server is: "Server: MySQL (127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP)", my version is: 5.7.21. So, in PhpMyAdmin, it appears that it works on localhost, but I don't find a solution in the WAMP server to change into public IP.

Comment: Ok thank you, it's the firewall, beginner mistake... thanks for your help!!

Comment: Be mindful when you expose your DB to the public internet, it's often getting ddos. Try not to use default 3306 port. Or if you only need to access within LAN then bind your mysql to your LAN IP instead.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your server already opens block 3306,

You need to enable remote access for the user (from localhost to "any") accessing the database.

[image]

Comment: Hello Ken, thank you for your answer! I actually configured the users to any host

Comment: Please check your firewall. Make sure it allows outbound connection thru port 3306

Comment: Ok guys, it's the firewall, beginner mistake... I forgot to open my port 3306... My god, thanks for your help!!